# I am receiving a 'General error: 1364' on Laravel saying I don't have a default value for username, can someone help me?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Right, so I have been getting this error for some time now:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'username' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (ggg, things@see.com, 2019-12-15 16:58:26, 2019-12-15 16:58:26))

I don't want to set username to `nullable`, as I need to have it. This is how the table looks like:

```
mysql> desc users;
+-------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name              | varchar(255)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email             | varchar(255)        | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| username          | varchar(255)        | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| email_verified_at | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| password          | varchar(255)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| remember_token    | varchar(100)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at        | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at        | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This is how the create method looks like:

```
     protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'username' => $data['username'],
        ]);
    }
```

That's where I am getting the error.

**EDIT:**
Okay, so I fixed it by moving the `'username'` attribute into the `$fillable` array. I also copied the original `App/User` class that Laravel provides and just added my methods to it.

Comment: Probably, you are trying to insert a record with an `null` name. You should check the process that writes to the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have added the field `username` to `$fillable` on the model:

```
protected $fillable = [
    ...
    'username',
];
```

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Eloquent - Mass Assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#mass-assignment) `$fillable`

Comment: Oh, that did something! Now I am getting this error though:

Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of App\User given, called in /home/vagrant/Laravel/petme/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/RegistersUsers.php on line 35

Comment: that is a separate issue .. your `App\User` model isn't extending from `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User` or implementing the `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable` directly ... this shouldn't really be an issue as the default `App\User` that you get with a clean install is setup for this already

Comment: I created a user class myself. This is probably what is causing it. Is there a way to fix this manually, or do I need to start from scratch? I am new to this sort of stuff, so I don't know.

Comment: have your `User` class extend `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User` or you will have to implement the `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable` interface yourself

Comment: I already have it extending Model. Do I just replace Model with Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User ?

Comment: yes ... that is the base class that implements that interface and extends Model already, assuming what Laravel version you are using

Answer (score 0):

You probably missing something of this:

- Check your migration and see do you have `nullable()` for that column
- As @lagbox mentioned check your `$fillable` fields

If error still exists you can try to edit in `config/databse.php`:

```
'mysql' => [
     ...
     'strict' => false,
]
```